# Opengl GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE in android

Tags: opengl-es

Rendering a texture into a rectangle(2 tri) with :

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                       GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                       GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
```

and no problem. But I dont want the texture to be stretched so Im trying to change to:

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                       GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                       GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

but everything I got is a black screen.

Is there any simple way to avoid a texture to fit the screen keeping the ratio?

This is where I load the texture

```
public static int loadTexture(final Context context, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        //final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();                       
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

This is the some of renderer code:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config)
{

    String vShaderStr = RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(this.context, R.raw.bulge_vertex_shader);

    String fShaderStr = RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(this.context, R.raw.bulge_fragment_shader);



    // Load the shaders and get a linked program object
    mProgramObject = ESShader.loadProgram(vShaderStr, fShaderStr);

    // Get the attribute locations
    mPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_position");
    mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_texCoord" );

    centerUniformLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "center");

    radiusUniformLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "radius");

    scaleUniformLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "scale");


    Bitmap b  = ((theApplication)context.getApplicationContext()).getBitmap();

    mTextureId = TextureHelper.loadTexture(this.context, b);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

}

// /
// Draw a triangle using the shader pair created in onSurfaceCreated()
//
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
{
    //distance += 0.01;


    // Set the viewport
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

    // Clear the color buffer
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use the program object
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

    // Load the vertex position
    mVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, 
                                   false, 
                                   5 * 4, mVertices );

    // Load the texture coordinate
    mVertices.position(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                                   false, 
                                   5 * 4, 
                                   mVertices );

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mPositionLoc );
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

    // Bind the texture
    GLES20.glActiveTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId );


    GLES20.glUniform2f(centerUniformLoc, mCenterData[0], mCenterData[1]);


    GLES20.glUniform1f(radiusUniformLoc, radius);

    GLES20.glUniform1f(scaleUniformLoc, scale);

    // Set the color matrix uniform unit to 1


    GLES20.glDrawElements ( GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices );
}
```

and the quad vertices with the texture coordinates

```
private final float[] mVerticesData =
{ 
        -1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 0
        0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 0
        -1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 1
        0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 1
        1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 2
        1.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 2
        1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 3
        1.0f, 0.0f // TexCoord 3
};


private final short[] mIndicesData =
{ 
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 
};
```

All I want is to see the texture scaled to the screen size but keeping the aspect ratio so it doesn't get stretched.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the complete snippet of texture creation and initialization that gives you the black screen? It's a little ambiguous from your description.

Comment: You realize that nowhere in your posted code is the clamp to edge line? Please post the **actual** code that exhibits the error. I'm sorry if this sounds trivial, but I'm trying to understand if you're replacing the min/mag filter lines with clamp to edge, or adding clamp to edge in addition.

Comment: Tim , maybe I didnt explaing myself clearly enough or u just didnt read the beginning of the post. At the beggining I wrote the two lines that work and the two lines lines that doesnt work. Im writing the lines that give me the black screen here again (int loadTexture method): GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                       GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                       GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Answer (score 6):

In order to avoid this black screen issue, you needed to *combine* the four lines as opposed to replacing the former two with the latter two. In your code, you were replacing

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
```

with

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                   GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                   GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Originally, I did the same thing; however, the correction should have been to add the clamping lines as opposed to replacing the filtering lines. The working code is a combination:

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                   GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                   GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```